# Computing similarities between pairs of words

Tags: python, scipy, spacy

This the code I am using to compute similarities between pairs of words.

```
computed_similarities=[]

for s in nlp.vocab.vectors:
    _:nlp.vocab[s]

for word in nlp.vocab:
    if word.has_vector:
        if word.is_lower:
            if word.is_alpha:
                similarity=cosine_similarity(new_vec,word.vector)
                computed_similarities.append((word,similarity))
        
computed_similarities=sorted (computed_similarities, key=lambda item:-item[1])

print([t[0].text for t in computed_similarities[:10] ])
```

What I didn't understand is what this piece of code means:

```
for s in nlp.vocab.vectors:
    _:nlp.vocab[s]
```

What does it do ?

Answer (score 0):

`x: y` is Python syntax for [variable type annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/). However, in this case the variable `_` is being annotated not with a type, but with the object `npl.vocab[s]`. If this code is run through a type checker this would be flagged, but a Python interpreter will not object to this, it will just store the annotation in the `__annotations__` dictionary. Since the annotation is run in a loop, it will be updated at each loop iteration.
Overall, I don't see the purpose of this part of the code, and it does not appear to be relevant to the rest of the code included in the question.